# Query to get all permissions or roles that has permission for single user

Tags: sql, postgresql

table set user to permission or some role - role may have some permissions

```
set_id|user_id|role_id|permission_id|set_to|add_time           |start_at|end_at|active|
------|-------|-------|-------------|------|-------------------|--------|------|------|
    15|      2|       |            7|{}    |2021-03-15 13:00:43|        |      |true  |
    16|      1|      1|             |{}    |2021-03-15 13:02:29|        |      |true  |
    14|      1|       |            7|{1,2} |2021-03-15 13:00:43|        |      |true  |
    17|       |      1|            7|{99}  |2021-03-15 13:02:43|        |      |true  |
```

question: trying to get user and his permissions and roles (if no permissions but set some role that has that permission)

trying like this:

```
select *  from permission_set ps
where ps.user_id = 1 
and ps.permission_id = 7  
or ps.role_id = any(select role_id from permission_set pss 
                    where pss.permission_id = 7  
                      and pss.active is true)
```

the problem is that roles comes in any way and i can't fix it.

Ps. DDL

```
CREATE TABLE public.permission_set (
    set_id serial NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NULL,
    role_id int4 NULL,
    permission_id int8 NULL,
    set_to _int4 NULL DEFAULT '{}'::integer[],
    add_time timestamp NULL DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()),
    start_at timestamp NULL,
    end_at timestamp NULL,
    active bool NULL DEFAULT true
);
```

Comment: What is this table, and what does it have to do with PostgreSQL permissions? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: because this i'm using postgres as a DB for my web project . i`m trying to realise user permission system for website